# Graphics drawn oval will not increase in size in java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 2d-games

I am writing a simple game in java using `Ovals` and the `Graphics` objects. It is called virus and works like this: There is an oval in the middle, and six ovals around the outside. These outside ovals are supposed to increase in size until clicked on, when they will disappear and the player scores ten points. If an oval touches the central oval, the health of the centre oval goes down. When it hits zero, the game ends. The problem im having is that the  outside ovals will not increase in size. Why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
package virus;


import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class VirusGamePanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;//serialVersionUID field
    Random colour = new Random();//the outside ovals will always be a random colour
    private int sizeX = 1;//the x size of the outside ovals 
    private int sizeY = 1;//the y size of the outside ovals
    int score = 0;
    static String scorestring = "Score: ";
    Color rand = new Color(colour.nextInt(255),colour.nextInt(255),colour.nextInt(255));//generate the random colour

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.magenta);
        g.drawString(scorestring+score,275,250);
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.drawOval(200,150,200,200);
        g.setColor(rand);
        g.drawOval(270,50,50,50);
        g.drawOval(100,100,50,50);
        g.drawOval(450,100,50,50);
        g.drawOval(100,400,50,50);
        g.drawOval(450,400,50,50);
        g.drawOval(275,450,50,50);
        g.fillOval(270,50,sizeX,sizeY);//these six ovals are supposed to increase in size
        g.fillOval(100,100,sizeX,sizeY);
        g.fillOval(450,100,sizeX,sizeY);
        g.fillOval(100,400,sizeX,sizeY);
        g.fillOval(450,400,sizeX,sizeY);
        g.fillOval(275,450,sizeX,sizeY);
        inc();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      JPanel panel = new VirusGamePanel();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Virus");
      frame.setSize(700, 700);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void inc()//increase the size of the ovals
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<25000; i++)
        {
            sizeX++;
            sizeY++;
            repaint();
        }
    }
```

New code with thread:

```
package virus;


import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class VirusGamePanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener,Runnable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Random colour = new Random();
    private int sizeX = 1;
    private int sizeY = 1;
    int score = 0;
    Thread thr = new Thread();
    static String scorestring = "Score: ";
    Color rand = new Color(colour.nextInt(255),colour.nextInt(255),colour.nextInt(255));

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        thr.start();
        g.setColor(Color.magenta);
        g.drawString(scorestring+score,275,250);
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.drawOval(200,150,200,200);
        g.setColor(rand);

        g.fillOval(270,50,sizeX,sizeY);
        g.fillOval(100,100,sizeX,sizeY);
        g.fillOval(450,100,sizeX,sizeY);
        g.fillOval(100,400,sizeX,sizeY);
        g.fillOval(450,400,sizeX,sizeY);
        g.fillOval(275,450,sizeX,sizeY);
        inc();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {}

    private void inc()
    {
        thr.run();
    }
    public void run(){
        for(int i = 0; i<25000; i++)
        {
            sizeX++;
            sizeY++;
            repaint();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But filling needs an empty area while you are using filloval on same location.

Comment: Try to change filloval to drawoval. If it works, then its about filling an already-filled area.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık You can edit your previously posted comments...

Comment: ok,i'll try removing the other ovals..back in a sec

Comment: @Baz: Okay i will keep in mind that.

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger?

Comment: No...i use eclipse but have no idea how 2 use the debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public class VirusGamePanel extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;//serialVersionUID field
    Random colour = new Random();//the outside ovals will always be a random colour
    private int sizeX = 0;//the x size of the outside ovals 
    private int sizeY = 0;//the y size of the outside ovals
    int score = 0;
    static String scorestring = "Score: ";
    Color rand = new Color(colour.nextInt(255), colour.nextInt(255), colour.nextInt(255)); //generate the random colour

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.magenta);
        g.drawString(scorestring+score,275,250);
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.drawOval(200, 150, 200, 200);
        g.setColor(rand);
        g.fillOval(270 - sizeX / 2, 50 - sizeY / 2, sizeX, sizeY);//these six ovals are supposed to increase in size
        g.fillOval(100 - sizeX / 2,100 - sizeY / 2, sizeX, sizeY);
        g.fillOval(450 - sizeX / 2,100 - sizeY / 2, sizeX, sizeY);
        g.fillOval(100 - sizeX / 2,400 - sizeY / 2, sizeX, sizeY);
        g.fillOval(450 - sizeX / 2,400 - sizeY / 2, sizeX, sizeY);
        g.fillOval(275 - sizeX / 2,450 - sizeY / 2, sizeX, sizeY);
        inc();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      JPanel panel = new VirusGamePanel();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Virus");
      frame.setSize(700, 700);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void inc()//increase the size of the ovals
    {
            sizeX++;
            sizeY++;
            repaint();
    }
}
```

Just fixed the center points of the ovals and removed the loop in the `inc` method. If you want the oval boundaries drawn, just add the `drawOval` commands with the same parameters as the `fillOval` commands.

**EDIT**:

If you want to slow down the growth process, just add the following just before the `inc()` call of the `paint` method:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Where are fillovals ? Your computer must be uber-fast.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık Changed `drawOval` to `fillOval`. Should now work as asked.

Comment: Thanks baz - IT WORKS :) just gotta slow down the size increase - they fill up the screen in about 1 second lol

Comment: @imulsion Glad I could help. Have fun with it. If you have no further questions, please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: One more question - I used a for loop to slow it down - for some reason it has actually sped up. Why is this?

Comment: @imulsion Just added a small paragraph to my answer. Basically, just add a `Thread.sleep()` to the `paint` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
 for(int i = 0; i<25000; i++)
    {
        sizeX++;
        sizeY++;
        repaint();
    }
```

Your computer cannot repaint as fast as your cpu increases sizeX and sizeY. Add some waiting time in milliseconds(especially if you draw a big area like 800x600)

```
 for(int i = 0; i<25000; i++)
    {
        sizeX++;
        sizeY++;
        repaint();
        try{ sleep(100);} catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }
```

But, do this from another thread! So, your app. will not freeze.

This is 10 FPS. But you tried 2G FPS. Good day.

Here is an example of a thread.

```
class TEN_FPS extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        while(working)
        {
             //calculations here
             repaint();
             try{sleep(100);}catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
     }
 }
```

Then in the main method:

```
working=true;
TEN_FPS.start();
```

When you are done with this program:

```
working=false;
```

will release your daemon thread.

Comment: Tried that - the JFrame just froze and now it won't close down

Comment: Did you use a thread before? I mean to make sleep only **that thread**. Okay, i am adding the thread now.

Comment: didn't work - I might be doing something wrong - i'll add my new code

Answer (score 2):

Your code is recursive.  In inc(), you call repaint, which calls VirusGamePanel.paint(), which calls inc() ...

Each call to repaint() will reinvoke the paint() method.  So instead of looping in inc() do this:

```
private void inc()// increase the size of the ovals
{
  sizeX++;
  sizeY++;
  repaint();
}
```

Comment: The ovals are meant to increase in size infinitely tho...by this method, they would only increase in size once

Comment: try it - Swing is doing the loop for you, you call paint, inc, repaint, paint, etc